# Don't serialize and unserialize (Pickle and Unpickle) the data while reading and writing from redis

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-redis

I am working in a system in which multiple code bases access the same redis instance, So while reading some data written from some other code base, in django framework, i am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django_redis/cache.py", line 32, in _decorator
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django_redis/cache.py", line 81, in get
    client=client)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django_redis/client/default.py", line 210, in get
    return self.decode(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django_redis/client/default.py", line 318, in decode
    value = self._serializer.loads(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django_redis/serializers/pickle.py", line 35, in loads
    return pickle.loads(value)
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '{'.
```

Basically Django is trying to de-serialize(unpickle) the data, though the data is not even serialized(pickeled).  Can i turn off this pickling and un-pickling in django-redis

Comment: you need to share codes regarding pickling and unpickling, without those we can't help you

Comment: actually i am not using my own algorithm for the same, I am using django framework, which already have this implemented.

Answer (score 4):

You can control the serialization behavior via the django caches options.  Try change the cache serializer to JSONSerializer or DummySerializer.

For example, if you are using the `django-redis-cache` package, change your cache setting to something like:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': ...,
        'LOCATION': ...,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'SERIALIZER_CLASS': 'redis_cache.serializers.JSONSerializer',
            ...
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that if you are using the `django-redis` package, the key & value of the option would be a little different:

```
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": ...,
        "LOCATION": ...,
        "OPTIONS": {
            ...
            "SERIALIZER": "django_redis.serializers.json.JSONSerializer",
        }
    }
}
```